# connect through a remote pc to take IP address

Tags: proxy, firewall, ip

We have a static IP address. This IP address is allowed to pass some of our customer's firewall. Problem is when we are outside the company, we are on our laptop. that uses a Internet key with dynamic IP addresses.

What would be the best way to use the Company's static IP address even when connecting from the laptop? Would setting up a proxy on a network-PC solve the problem?

Comment: This would require setting up a VPN server.

Comment: with a VPN i would be able to access the web using the static IP address of the company??

Comment: With a VPN you would be part of the network and be  assigned the same static ip as everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Start a VPN connection from your laptop to connect to your own companies network.
2. Login on the computer on your companies network which has the IP which is allowed to connect to the customers network.
3. Connect though your customers firewall from that PC. If that is done via another VPN (likely) then configuring this might be *fun*.